# Computed value in VueJs - usage in asynch call

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, nuxt.js

I'm creating a dynamic array in the `computed:` part of my .vue file. This array has a set of urls I each want to call (in a repeated component), to get articles. These articles vary, so on page render the computed array is made, and when that's done I want to call the urls the moment my component is made.

```js
computed: {
    calcTheArray() {
        // make the actual array
        // basically, I grab a (computed! so can't use that in async either) 
        // array with months that have passed before today
        // I create an array with combined urls, that incorporate those month names
        // no other dependencies exist
        return array;
    }
},
```

then:

```js
async asyncData({ error, app, }) {
    try {
        // lots of things happen here, another api call, some parsing etc.

        const promises = [];
        this.calcTheArray.forEach((value) => {
            promises.push(app.$axios.$get(`${value}`, { useCache: true }));
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return error({ statusCode: 500, message: e.message });
    }
},
```

The error I'm getting is: `Cannot read property 'calcTheArray' of undefined`

And I sort of understand *why* that is, as the async function is... well asynchronous, so my data doesn't exist yet? I think? But then how would I go about getting the dynamically created urls into my axios call?

What I've tried so far, is seeing whether the `this.calcTheArray` was the culprit and trying different ways to use the calculated array (`vm.calcTheArray`, just `calcTheArray` for example) I've also tried to define my the array in the `data() {` part

```js
data() {
    return {
      calcTheArray: [],
    };
  },
```

But then I (obviously) end up with a `Duplicated key 'calcTheArray'`.

I'm at a loss. Can anyone give me a pointer?

Comment: Assuming this is Nuxt, see https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/. Quote *'You do **NOT** have access of the component instance through `this` inside `asyncData` because it is called before initiating the component.'*. Without knowing what `calcTheArray` depends on it is difficult to advise further.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, I'm using Nuxt. `calcTheArray` only depends on todays date (or its month to be more precise). For all past months from a starting point until this month, I have a different API call to make. I dynamically build those from an array of month names. That's pretty much all `calcTheArray` does.

I now do understand I why I can't use the `calcTheArray` in the async, but it's still unclear to me what I should do instead to get the calls working...

Comment: Could you not move the code from `calcTheArray` into your `asyncData` function?

Comment: I just updated my code... the array I reference is also calculated...

Comment: So what are the ultimate dependencies of all the relevant computed properties? e.g. Do they depend on any props, etc.? Is there actually anything from the instance that you need or have you just used computed properties for convenience? Is there any reason these can't just be defined as normal JavaScript functions, totally separate from your Vue component options?

Comment: No... I think that's where I went wrong actually. They probably would be fine as regular functions. I'm new to VueJS, and looking at the codebase I'm working with I assumed I needed to do things this way.

You're right though, for now I've moved all the bits I computed right into the async function, and that seems to work (still not quite there, but the problem above looks solved!).

Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to execute the async method only when the calcTheArray has actually some value computed and prevent the undefined error. You can use a watcher to trigger the async function in that case, you could try the following:

```
computed: {
    calcTheArray() {
        // your code to create the array;
        return array;
    }
},
watch: {
    calcTheArray() {
        // executed when there's any mutation detected by vue on calcTheArray;
        this.asyncData(object)
    }
},
methods: {
    async asyncData({ error, app, }) {
      try {
         // lots of things happen here, another api call, some parsing etc.

         const promises = [];
         this.calcTheArray.forEach((value) => {
            promises.push(app.$axios.$get(`${value}`, { useCache: true }));
         });
       } catch (e) {
         console.log(e);
         return error({ statusCode: 500, message: e.message });
       }
   }
}
```

This way, vue will wait to the computed array before start the async method. Hope it suits you well.

Comment: This is looking really logical... For my situation, the actual watching isn't needed, as the articles will be loaded on page load, but I did gain some insights from your answer. Thank you!